# Compiling Xcode projects through Terminal

Tags: xcode, command-line, compilation, terminal

I would like to know how one can compile an entire Xcode project through Terminal/Command Line

Comment: +1 to counter unexplained downvoting

Comment: +1 @Justin: good idea, me too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`xcodebuild`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcodebuild/), the program that builds xcode projects.  There is a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcodebuild) for this if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `xcodebuild` binary.
More informations [here](http://www.google.com)